# How can we take all ripple aka XRP accounts snapshot?

Tags: rippled, xrp

How can we take a snapshot of all ripple accounts. I know we can use this api and but it has 1000  `https://data.ripple.com/v2/accounts/?`
but this has a max limit of 1000 and to get snapshot of all accounts of xrp can take too long is there any better way to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the request with parameters:

```
https://data.ripple.com/v2/accounts?start=1000&limit=5
```

[Here](https://github.com/ripple/rippled-historical-database#get-accounts) is the API description.